# Check if all Input component fields are filled, then enable submit button

Tags: react-native, native-base

I want it so that when all  fields are filled(i.e. not empty), the submit button will be enabled. I could implement this easily if the number of fields were fixed, but in this case, the number of fields won't be fixed, such as items in a shopping cart. Here is my code so far:

```
{orders.map((order, i) => (
<Row key={i}>
    <Col>
        <Row><Text>{o.quantity}</Text><Text>{`${order.name}`}</Text></Row>
    </Col>
    <Col> 
        <Item fixedLabel>
                <Label>$</Label>
                <Input placeholder={"0.00"} value={order.price} />
        </Item>
    </Col>
</Row>
))}
<Button disabled={this.state.disabled} onPress={this.submit.bind(this)}><Text>Submit</Text></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the initial state of `disabled` as `false`. Then, do as follows...

```
{orders.map((order, i) => {
  if(!order.name || !order.value) { this.setState({ disabled: true }) }
  <Row key={i}>
    <Col>
      <Row><Text>{o.quantity}</Text><Text>{`${order.name}`}</Text></Row>
    </Col>
    <Col> 
      <Item fixedLabel>
        <Label>$</Label>
        <Input placeholder={"0.00"} value={order.price} />
      </Item>
    </Col>
  </Row>
})}
<Button disabled={this.state.disabled} onPress={this.submit.bind(this)}><Text>Submit</Text></Button>
```

Here, it checks if the `name` or `value` of the particular order is null. If it found at least a one `order` with `name` or `value` of the particular order is null, it sets the `disabled` as `true`.

Comment: Not really what I had in mind. I want it so that if ALL inputs fields are filled, the submit button is enabled, not if ONE OF them was filled. Also order.value is not a field in the orders array, so no point in checking for that.

Comment: Yes, it does. I meant, if it found at least one which is NOT filled, it will disable the button.